# Why is the head getting affected when I call my reverse function vs the case at the bottom? I get the none error

Tags: python, linked-list

Here's the code. The head and the dummy node in ispalindrome gets changed after I call the reverse function. Any reason why this happens? I have a case in the bottom of doing the same thing where head doesn't get changed.

```
class ListNode(object):
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.val=x
        self.next=None
def reverse(head,l):
    prev=None
    while head:
        head.next,prev,head=prev,head,head.next
        l+=1
    return (prev,l)

def isPalindrome(head):
    dummy=head
    rev,l=reverse(head,0)
    print (rev.val,dummy.next.val)

a=ListNode(1)
a.next=ListNode(2)

isPalindrome(a)
```

I did something similar here to test out my logic and this is the way I imagined my code to turn out: When I call reverse, I can still access the head and the b variable assigned to it.

```
class ListNode(object):
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.val=x
        self.next=None
a=ListNode(1)
a.next=ListNode(2)
b=a
def reverse(head,l):
    prev=None
    while head:
        head.next,prev,head=prev,head,head.next
        l+=1
    return (prev,l)
rev,l=reverse(a,0)
print b.val,rev.val
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is that your `reverse` function is destructive. That is, it creates a reversed list by modifying the list you pass to it. Afterwards, the original list doesn't exist in the same form any more.

This is problematic for a palindrome test, since you want to compare the list to its own reverse. If the original doesn't exist any more, the reversed version isn't very useful.

While there are various ways you could avoid your specific error, to solve the larger problem of getting a reversed list while still having a copy of the original, I think there is an easy fix. You can change the logic of `reverse` to create a copy of the list in reversed order, rather than modifying the original:

```
def reverse_copy(head, l):
    new_list = None
    while head:
        temp = Node(head.val)
        temp.next, new_list = new_list, temp
        l += 1
    return new_list, l
```

Now you can have `isPalindrome` do `rev, l = reverse_copy(head)`, and still have `head` refer to the original list!

Answer (score 1):

In the first version you store the original head to `dummy` and then reverse the list. This of course causes `dummy` to be the last node in the reversed list. Then you try to access value of next element from `dummy`: `dummy.next.val` This obviously fails because `dummy.next` is `None`.

On the second example you're not accessing the links at all, only the values. When you reverse the list you only change the links between the nodes but not the values so you can't detect the change.

**Update** To illustrate better on what's happening here I've added a new function that displays the list before and after reversal:

```
def to_str(head):
    l = []
    while head:
        l.append(str(head.val))
        l.append('->')
        head = head.next
    l.append('None')

    return ' '.join(l)

def isPalindrome(head):
    dummy=head
    print 'Before (dummy): {}'.format(to_str(dummy))
    rev,l=reverse(head,0)
    print 'After (dummy): {}'.format(to_str(dummy))
    print 'After (rev): {}'.format(to_str(rev))
    print (rev.val,dummy.next.val)
```

If you replace the original `isPalindrome` with above you get following output:

```
Before (dummy): 1 -> 2 -> None
After (dummy): 1 -> None
After (rev): 2 -> 1 -> None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 34, in <module>
    isPalindrome(a)
  File "test.py", line 29, in isPalindrome
    print (rev.val,dummy.next.val)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'val'
```

Comment: Why would dummy be the last node when it's pointing to the first node? Like in the second example b=a where a is the head. The cases look almost identical to me, I still don't understand. Can you explain what you mean by the second paragraph "accessing the links at all". I'm reversing the head in the second case as well.

Comment: @Haxet It **was** pointing to the first node and then list got reversed. When you reverse the list with `reverse` the same node will be at the very end of the reversed list. In the second example you're not trying to navigate from one node another so you won't notice any difference because `reverse` will only change the `next` property of `ListNode` and `val` remains the same.